# Search function with "Enter" key in Japanese

Tags: php, html

I am facing a problem with Japanese. I have a form that allows users can search the data. When users input the string to search and press "Enter" key, the search function will execute. My code is:

```
$('#formSearch input').keyup(function(event){
    var key = event.charCode||event.keyCode||0;
    if(key == 13){
         $("#formSearch").submit();
    }
});
```

But when users input Japanese in Hiragana mode, the editor show the predict words. They press "Enter" and the search function is execute. It does not correct. Anyone can tell me how to fix this problem.Thank you so much

Comment: @Adder The OP's question may not be perfect English, but at the very least it seems pretty obvious they are not talking about character code conversion. I think the OP "put effort" into his question, therefore if you don't like their English perhaps you could make an edit instead of telling them to "learn English". http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/07/non-english-question-policy/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you're listening for an <kbd>Enter</kbd> key press (keyup).
As you probably know, when typing Japanese in Hiragana mode, a list of possible kanji characters appears as you type. <kbd>Enter</kbd> is one of the keys used to confirm the kanji selection so most Japanese users will end up pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> twice when they search for something. Your script executes on the first press so the second "submit" press is ignored.

A better alternative is to listen for a `submit` event instead of a `keyup` event. In jQuery you can use the `.submit()` method like this:

```
$("#formSearch").submit(function() {
  // Code to execute here
});
```

In your case, however, you don't seem to have any further script to execute, so maybe you don't need JavaScript at all. Try the form without JavaScript — if you can't submit it with <kbd>Enter</kbd> (in English or Japanese) there's probably a problem with your HTML so please update your question with your form's code.