# Distinguishing between "Enter" keypress for Japanese kanji suggestion and other "Enter" events

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

My question is somewhat related to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13987195/search-function-with-enter-key-in-japanese). However, I do not have the luxury to listen for the `submit` event so the answer to that question will not work for me.

My question: **Is it possible in Javascript to detect when the Japanese/Chinese suggestion menu is open? Or is there another way to distinguish an <kbd>Enter</kbd> keypress that is to accept the Japanese/Chinese character suggestion from any other <kbd>Enter</kbd> keypress?**

The reason the solution from the other question will not work for my situation is that I am currently overriding the textarea functionality with JavaScript so that an <kbd>Enter</kbd> keypress submits the form instead of making a newline.

Therefore I want to be able to distinguish between an <kbd>Enter</kbd> keypress that is to accept a character suggestion for Japanese or Chinese and for any other <kbd>Enter</kbd> keypress I want to submit the form.

Comment: Very related... http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63644/pressing-enter-in-comment-box-unexpectedly-submits-form/64323#64323 :)

Comment: @deceze Thanks for the link. This [answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/217498) on a linked question from your link actually answers the question. The answer is to use keydown instead of keyup. If you want to write that up as the answer I'll give you some internet points :)

Comment: Does that *actually* work on all platforms under all IMEs? I'll let you test that out and write an answer yourself... :)

Answer (score 2):

I use the following check to determine whether any keyboard event is happening inside that window (IME)

```
event.isComposing || event.keyCode === 229
```

`isComposing` alone is not enough, as Safari has a bug

`keyCode` is deprecated

But it's better than nothing, hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

Using the `keydown` event instead of the `keyup` event (discovered in this [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/217498)) seems to work in the latest versions of Chrome, Firefox and Safari using the Mac IME. I haven't been able to test it in Explorer or using any other IMEs. If anyone can share results under other browsers or IMEs it would be great to know.

Answer (score 0):

I used a similar concept to Andrey's answer, but in the TextField component from MUI, `isComposing` was not available in the event object and I ended up using `onCompositionStart` and `onCompositionEnd`

Here is the snippet.

```
const Component = () => {
  const [composing, setComposing] = useState<boolean>(false);
  const handleEnter: React.KeyboardEventHandler = (e) => {
    if (composing) {
      return;
    }
    if (e.code === "Enter") {
      // the logic to handle the submit
    }
  };
  return (
    <TextField
      onKeyDown={handleEnter}
      onCompositionStart={() => {
        setComposing(true);
      }}
      onCompositionEnd={() => {
        setComposing(false);
      }}
    />
  );
};
```

In my research, I also found some solutions which use `onKeyPress` or `e.keyCode`, but both are deprecated.

Comment: I had race conditions with this. State was not updated in time.